# JAVA Keep decimal places only when it got value

Tags: java

i need the decimal places output to be like this:
1000.00 -> 1000
1000.10 -> 1000.10
remove trailing zero if decimal places is both zero, but
keep two decimal places if there is at least one value.

I tried DecimalFormat(".##"), but its not what im looking for:
1000
1000.1 (need to keep two decimal places 1000.10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following for 2 decimal places or none.

```
if ((long) x == x) {
   System.out.println((long) x);
} else {
   System.out.printf("%.2f%n", x);
}
```